# ClassCastException when using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, hql

See the following mapping

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Integer someField;

}
```

When i call the following query

```
select someField, count(*) from SomeClass inner join OtherClass... group by ...
```

And i proccess the query as follows

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

List<Object> objectList = query.list();
for(Object object: objectList) {
    Object [] objectArray = (Object []) object;

    result.put((Integer) objectArray[0], (Integer) objectArray[1]);
}
```

I get ClassCastException: can not convert Long to Integer

Question: what should i do to retrieve the values returned by the HQL as Integer instead of Long ????

Comment: Both answers are correct! (+1) Trank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know which it will be (`Integer` or `Long`), you can cast to `Number` and call `intValue()` or `longValue()`.  This way an `Integer` or a `Long` will work.

```
result.put((Integer) objectArray[0], ((Number) objectArray[1]).intValue() );
```

The small downside with this is you end up unboxing the Number and reboxing it to put in the map.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the second column in the result - i.e. `count(*)` returns `Long`. You can get its int value by `((Long) objectArray[1]).intValue()`

Or (as suggested), better change your map to `Map<Integer, Long>`, so that no information is eventually lost.

Comment: Note that you may lose information. Rather just use `Long` instead of `Integer`.